# video recorder on iphone

Tags: iphone, video

This is the program that i make.
But i doesn't run good. when i open this program on iphone it immediatly turn off.
I will show my code and answer me what is the problem.

```
UIImagePickerController * videoRecorder = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    videoRecorder.delegate = self;
    videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoRecorder.sourceType];
    if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie] ) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                        message:@"Device Not Supported for video Recording."     
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"No",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }
    videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    videoRecorder.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];           
    videoRecorder.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
    videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 120;
    videoRecorder.delegate = self;
    self.recorder_ = videoRecorder;                 
    [videoRecorder release];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.recorder_ animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Use the code formatter in the future please.  This hurts to look at.

Second: You're double releasing UIImagePicketController (videoRecorder)  auto-release will release it after the current runloop exits, but you're also explicitly releasing it near the end of your method call here, so when iOS cleans up the auto-release pool, it will get a double release and crash.

I can't read the rest of this well due to the formatting, but that seems like your most likely bet for what's causing the crash.

Comment: Ok, next issue:  If you're going to save a reference to videoRecorder, you don't want to release it here.  If this gets called from the run-loop, it will be deallocated when the function returns with auto-release, and releasing it explicitly before then will invalidate the reference anyway, and deallocate the object. (hence the crash)  If you're going to use this object in another run loop, you MUST NOT deallocate it.  `self.recorder_ = videoRecorder;` Is what makes me think you don't really want to release this object.

Comment: Thank you. I remove the autorelease as you say but it still turn off.

Comment: Are you re-using the "recorder" property later?  There's no reason to keep it if not, but it's pointing to the object that is deallocated when `[videoRecorder release];` is called.  You really need to read up on memory management here.  Assigning the pointer to another variable is not the same as a copy.  Both variables point to the same object, and you are releasing that object, making the "recorder" property invalid.  You should release the UIImagePickerController when your object (the one this code is from) is destroyed, or else ensure it's in the same auto-release context as your object is

Comment: Using an invalid pointer WILL crash your application incidentally, and I doubt the crash is within the segment of code you've supplied here, but instead in something that uses results from this code.  Come to think of it, a stack trace on the crash would be VERY HELPFUL to diagnose what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your post and make the code readable.

The problem is that you autorelease videoRecorder in the first line so you don't have to call the -release. videoRecorder has a retain count of zero in the first line and a retain count of one when you assign it to self.recorder_. When you call the release, then retain count goes to zero and the autorelease pool makes the object go away before the recorder can be presented as a modal view controller. Remove that -release call and you should be fine. Also, your code sets the delegate and sourceType two times.

Comment: Thank you. I remove the autorelease but it still turn off. Is there another reason? I can't find it out.